# select xml from one table with updated data(values) from another table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

I want to generate XML from existing xml but values should come from some other table. For example I have following xml in a table:

```
<LABEL COLOR=RED> Account #: </LABEL>
<VALUE> ACCT_NUM </VALUE>
<LABEL COLOR=RED> Emp. Name: </LABEL>
<VALUE> Emp_Name </VALUE>
```

Table for data looks like this:

**EmployeeAccount**

```
ACCT_NUM   Emp_Name
1234       Kash
```

Now it should generate xml in following format

```
<LABEL COLOR=RED> Account #: </LABEL>
<VALUE> 1234 </VALUE>
<LABEL COLOR=RED> Emp. Name: </LABEL>
<VALUE> Kash </VALUE>
```

I can't find any way of doing this after two days of googling.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this using ...

```
`DECLARE @t TABLE (id INT, data XML)
DECLARE @t2 TABLE (id INT, value varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @t (id, data)
SELECT 1,
'
<data>
  <label>1</label>
  <value>test</value>
</data>
'

INSERT INTO @t2 (id, value)
SELECT 1, 'Kash' union all
SELECT 2, 'Moeen'

--Update value of an element in xml from other table
UPDATE t1
SET data.modify
(
'
replace value of (//value/text())[1] with sql:column("value")
'
)
FROM @t t1
INNER JOIN @t2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id

SELECT data FROM @t
`
```